# Google analytics default session timeout for app

Tags: android, ios, session, google-analytics

I would like to know what is default session timeout of GA mobile SDK ? (Both IOS and Android)

According to Android SDK reference :
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/parameters

> The amount of time (in seconds) your application can stay in the background before the session is ended. Default is 30 seconds. Setting this to a negative number will result in a new session never being started by the SDK. However, session timeout can still be managed in the Google Analytics admin interface, see Session and campaign timeout handling (Help Center) for details.

What '''**session timeout can still be managed in the Google Analytics admin interface**''' meaning ? If do nothing , admin interface is configure session timeout as 30 minutes.

So what is default timeout of GA mobile SDK ? 30 minutes or 30 seconds ?

Answer (score 0):

"30 Seconds" has gotta be a typo. Its 30 minutes on the admin interface and its 30 minutes for iOS https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sessions